# Move files by date into different directory using CLI

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, files, timestamps

I have a large number of pictures from an old hard drive that I'm trying to organize. If I run `ls -l`, I notice all of these files have a creation date of 2012 or before. Ideally, I'd like to move these to my computer's second hard drive, which is not set to mount automatically. Preferably, I could do this all as a batch with some commands linked together. So far, I have `ls -l | grep -i 2012` which spits out only the files with 2012 in the date provided by `ls -l`. Now, the trick would be `cp`'ing all of those files to the new directory. I'm not sure where to go next with this because each file would have to be copied. What would be my next set of commands?

Answer (score 15):

Do not use `ls`. It's not recommended to use in such cases. Moreover using `grep` to filter according to date is not a good idea. You filename might itself contain `2012` string, even though it was not modified in 2012.

Use `find` command and pipe its output.

```
find . -newermt 20120101 -not -newermt 20130101 -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t /your/target/directory
```

Here,

```
-newermt 20120101  ==>  File's modified date should be newer than 01 Jan 2012
-not               ==>  reverses the following condition. Hence file should be older than 01 Jan 2013
-print0 and -0     ==>  Use this options so that the command doesn't fail when filenames contain spaces
```

Comment: Won't `-exec mv {} /your/target/directory \;' instead of '-print 0 | xargs -0 cp -t /your/target/directory' work just as good regarding problems with spaces in names? (Also, the OP wanted to *move* not *copy*)

Comment: ^^ Yes. Both achieve the same objective.

Answer (score 4):

If you have newer files on the old disk that you want to ignore I would go about it like this

1. Create a temporary marker file with a modified-by date that separates files I want from those I don't
2. Copy files older than the marker file to the new location

Here are sample commands for this, which assume you want to maintain any directory hierarchy from the old disk in the new (`cpio` is a copy command, similar to `tar` or `pax`):

```
touch -t 201201010000 /tmp/marker    # YYYYMMDDhhmm == Jan 1st, 2012
cd /path/to/old/disk
find . -type f \! -newer /tmp/marker -print0 | cpio -pmd0 /path/to/new/disk
```

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe this issue is very the same as yours, you also can check this out: [Create sub-directories and organize files by date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66494/create-sub-directories-and-organize-files-by-date)

I write this new script based on that issue's first answer:

```
for x in *; do
  d=$(date -r "$x" +%Y)
  mkdir -p "/your/new/directory/$d"
  mv -- "$x" "/your/new/directory/$d/"
done
```

1. write this script to a file named `copy.sh` in your old directory.
2. replace the `/your/new/directory` with your new directory's path
3. make this file executable with `chmod +x copy.sh`
4. then execute this file by `./copy.sh`

Comment: You might want to add some exception handling, so the script doesn't move *itself* into a `2015` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use a batch tool for batch operations. Doing so will usually entail reading/writing all records in a single stream rather than, for example, invoking a separate `cp` process for each file copied.

There is already a `cpio` answer written here, which, given only the options already provided you is likely what I would choose. However, the `cpio` format has been improved upon and folded into the standardized `pax` archive format since its heyday. The same is true of `tar`.

A strictly POSIX-`pax` will not likely provide any options for directly filtering archive members based on file modification times - though the standard does specify the `%T` list-mode format-modifier. Still, the most commonly available `pax` implementation that I know of - which is the BSD version maintained by [mirabilos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/43720/mirabilos) - does extend this into a directly accessible CLI-switch.

For example, to copy only all files in the tree rooted at `./` which were last modified before `ccyymmddHHMM` to `/target/dir` you could do:

```
pax -rwT,201301010000 ./ /target/dir
```

To avoid recursing into child directories you might do instead:

```
pax -rwdT,201301010000 ./* /target/dir
```

See the [`man`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pax) page for more.

Comment: I guess I really ought to learn `pax`, but `tar` and `cpio` still stand me well. +1

Comment: @roaima - strictly speaking, while there is an actual `pax` archive format *(which is an extension to the **ustar** format)*, the POSIX-spec'd `pax` *utility* reads/writes cpio, pax, and ustar formats. Because all three archive types amount primarily just to different means of encoding the metadata for many files alongside said files' actual data into a single stream, it isn't really too much of a stretch. I once wrote [`shitar`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151057/52934) - which was just a few lines of shell-script for - mostly `dd` - `tar`ing block devs on the fly based on the POSIX spec.

Comment: I like your linked script; strangely it would have been very useful a couple of months ago for exactly that same purpose. Oh well. I might even try to stop using `cpio -H ustar` ...